# Customize how the smooth confidence interval is computed

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use to plot the `loess` estimation of a bunch of points along with the confidence interval by means of the `geom_smooth` function.

Now I need to change the method by which the confidence bounds are computed (i.e. I need to change the shape of the blur band). Is there a way to do that in `geom_smooth`?

Or, how can I emulate it with `ggplot2`? How can I such a blur band?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a to plot something that isn't one of the options in `geom_smooth` your best bet is to manually fit the model yourself.

You haven't said what method you need. 
But here is an example of fitting the loess with family symmetric and computing the standard errors of that.

```
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

# The original plot using the default loess method
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_smooth(method = 'loess', se = TRUE)

# Fit loess model with family = 'symmetric'
#   Replace the next 2 lines with whatever different method you need
loess_smooth <- loess(d$x ~ d$y, family = 'symmetric')

# Predict the model over the range of data you are interested in.
loess_pred <- predict(loess_smooth, 
                      newdata = seq(min(d$x), max(d$x), length.out = 1000), 
                      se = TRUE)

loess.df <- data.frame(fit = loess_pred$fit, 
                       x =  seq(min(d$x), max(d$x), length.out = 1000), 
                       upper = loess_pred$fit + loess_pred$se.fit, 
                       lower = loess_pred$fit - loess_pred$se.fit)

# plot to compare
p + 
  geom_ribbon(data = loess.df, aes(x = x, y = fit, ymax = upper, ymin = lower), alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_line(data = loess.df, aes(x = x, y = fit))
```

[image: Two loess fits]